# CSS create a grid with 2 columns of 80%width

Tags: css

i'm trying to create a grid with 2 columns containing each a picture on the left and a text on the right.

my image keep taking most of the space and be the only item on its, even when i set a new width on it it doesn't take it in count, how can i get a 2 column grid where each column is constituted of a block of an image on the left and text on the right ?

Here's an example:

```css
.menuFormation {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 40vw 40Vw;
    grid-template-rows: 30vh 30vh;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    width: 90vw;
    justify-items: center;
}

.formationContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 20vw;
    object-fit: contain;
}

.formationImage{
    width: 10px;
}

.blocTexteFormation {
    font-size: large;
}
```

```html
    <main>
        <section>
            <h1>Formations</h1>
        </section>
        <section class="menuFormation">
            <div class="formationContainer"> 
                <img class= "formationImage" src="https://www.toureiffel.paris/sites/default/files/actualite/image_principale/vue_depuisjardins_webbanner_3.jpg">
                <div class="blocTexteFormation">Ceci est le texte que nous importerons depuis PHP</div>
            </div>
            <div class="formationContainer">
                <img class= "formationImage" src="https://www.toureiffel.paris/sites/default/files/actualite/image_principale/vue_depuisjardins_webbanner_3.jpg">
                <div class="blocTexteFormation">Ceci est le texte que nous importerons depuis PHP</div>
            </div>
            <div class="formationContainer">
                <img class= "formationImage" src="https://www.toureiffel.paris/sites/default/files/actualite/image_principale/vue_depuisjardins_webbanner_3.jpg">
                <div class="blocTexteFormation">Ceci est le texte que nous importerons depuis PHP</div>
            </div>
            <div class="formationContainer">
                <img class= "formationImage" src="https://www.toureiffel.paris/sites/default/files/actualite/image_principale/vue_depuisjardins_webbanner_3.jpg">
                <div class="blocTexteFormation">Ceci est le texte que nous importerons depuis PHP</div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
```

ichanged the pictures from local ones for some eiffel tower picture found on the internet but the idea is the same

Thanks for the time taken reading me

Answer (score 1):

Updated example:

```css
.menuFormation {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    gap: 20px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.formationContainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    gap: 10px;
}
.formationImage {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
      <h1>Formations</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="menuFormation">
      <div class="formationContainer"> 
          <img class= "formationImage" src="https://www.toureiffel.paris/sites/default/files/actualite/image_principale/vue_depuisjardins_webbanner_3.jpg">
          <div class="blocTexteFormation">Ceci est le texte que nous importerons depuis PHP</div>
      </div>
      <div class="formationContainer">
          <img class= "formationImage" src="https://www.toureiffel.paris/sites/default/files/actualite/image_principale/vue_depuisjardins_webbanner_3.jpg">
          <div class="blocTexteFormation">Ceci est le texte que nous importerons depuis PHP</div>
      </div>
      <div class="formationContainer">
          <img class= "formationImage" src="https://www.toureiffel.paris/sites/default/files/actualite/image_principale/vue_depuisjardins_webbanner_3.jpg">
          <div class="blocTexteFormation">Ceci est le texte que nous importerons depuis PHP</div>
      </div>
      <div class="formationContainer">
          <img class= "formationImage" src="https://www.toureiffel.paris/sites/default/files/actualite/image_principale/vue_depuisjardins_webbanner_3.jpg">
          <div class="blocTexteFormation">Ceci est le texte que nous importerons depuis PHP</div>
      </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Grid to create a two-column grid layout. You can define the grid columns and rows, and then assign each element on the page to a specific cell. For example, you can assign the image to the left column and the text to the right column. You can also set a width on the image to make sure it takes up the desired amount of space.

Here is an example of the CSS code:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

And then in the HTML:

```html
<div class="grid">
  <img class="img" src="image.jpg" />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated Code, try this

```css
.menuFormation {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 40vw 40Vw;
    grid-template-rows: 30vh 30vh;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    width: 90vw;
    justify-items: center;
}

.formationContainer {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: nowrap;
   width: 20vw;
   object-fit: contain;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
.formationImage{
    width: 20%;
}

.blocTexteFormation {
    font-size: large;
}
```

```html
    <main>
        <section>
            <h1>Formations</h1>
        </section>
        <section class="menuFormation">
            <div class="formationContainer"> 
                <img class= "formationImage" src="https://www.toureiffel.paris/sites/default/files/actualite/image_principale/vue_depuisjardins_webbanner_3.jpg">
                <div class="blocTexteFormation">Ceci est le texte que nous importerons depuis PHP</div>
            </div>
            <div class="formationContainer">
                <img class= "formationImage" src="https://www.toureiffel.paris/sites/default/files/actualite/image_principale/vue_depuisjardins_webbanner_3.jpg">
                <div class="blocTexteFormation">Ceci est le texte que nous importerons depuis PHP</div>
            </div>
            <div class="formationContainer">
                <img class= "formationImage" src="https://www.toureiffel.paris/sites/default/files/actualite/image_principale/vue_depuisjardins_webbanner_3.jpg">
                <div class="blocTexteFormation">Ceci est le texte que nous importerons depuis PHP</div>
            </div>
            <div class="formationContainer">
                <img class= "formationImage" src="https://www.toureiffel.paris/sites/default/files/actualite/image_principale/vue_depuisjardins_webbanner_3.jpg">
                <div class="blocTexteFormation">Ceci est le texte que nous importerons depuis PHP</div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, the image is taking up most of the space because its width is set to 10 pixels in the .formationImage class. To make the image and text blocks take up equal width in their respective columns, you can set the grid-template-columns property to a percentage value for each column.

```
.menuFormation {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  width: 90vw;
  justify-items: center;
}

.formationContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.formationImage {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.blocTexteFormation {
  font-size: large;
}
```